# How to create a string input field flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

My emulator looks like

[image: Android Emulator]

How to create a string input field flutter?

Change the keyboard type as text and input value as a string for the text field name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
 keyboardType: TextInputType.text
```

Check my main.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';void main() => runApp(new MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    Color hexToColor(String code) {
      return new Color(int.parse(code.substring(1, 7), radix: 16) + 0xFF000000);
    }return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: "End User Page",
        home: new Material(
            child: new Container (
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                color: Colors.white,
                child: new Container(
                  child: new Center(
                      child: new Column(
                          children : [
                            new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 140.0)),
                            new Text('Name:',
                              style: new TextStyle(color: hexToColor("#F2A03D"), fontSize: 25.0),),
                            new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0)),
                            new TextFormField(
                              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                labelText: "Enter Name",
                                fillColor: Colors.white,
                                border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                                  borderSide: new BorderSide(
                                  ),
                                ),
                                //fillColor: Colors.green
                              ),
                              validator: (val) {
                                if(val.length==0) {
                                  return "Name cannot be empty";
                                }else{
                                  return null;
                                }
                              },
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: "Poppins",
                              ),
                            ),
                          ]
                      )
                  ),)


            )
        )
    );}
}
```

Output:

[image: Emulator]

Cheers!

Comment: Have you answered your own question, or have you accidentally added part of your question as an answer? If so, please take this content and add it to your original question and remove this answer.

Comment: Sorry for answer my own question, I searched for an hours for this answer and it will be helpful someone that is reason i posted an answer also. @JoaoSoares